# Compare two dates but with current year

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell with a date:

```
30/04/1991
```

I need to make a compare with today's date, but with day and month of that cell, but with current year. But it isn't working.

I have the following:

```
MsgBox Format(Day(cell.Value) & "/" & Month(cell.Value) & "/" & Year(Now), "dd/mm/yyyy") < Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

The result is "30/04/2017 < 01/05/2017"
But msgbox result is "False". Which is wrong, given today's date as "01/05/2017"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself with

```
MsgBox DateValue(Day(cell.Value) & "/" & Month(cell.Value) & "/" & Year(Now)) < DateValue(Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid issues with February 29th, you can compare just the month and date:

```
MsgBox Format(cell, "mmdd") < Format(Now, "mmdd")
```

**Update**

[`DatePart("y", Date)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251733.aspx) can be used to get the Day of year:

```
 MsgBox DatePart("y", cell) < DatePart("y", Now)

 Debug.Print DatePart("y", "2 28")     // 59
 Debug.Print DatePart("y", "2 29 16")  // 60
```

Comment: Well thought, the February 29th.

Comment: interesting that `CDate("2 28")` results in 2/28/2017, but `CDate("2 29")` in  2/1/2029 (and `CDate("2 29 17")` in "Type mismatch" error)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `DateDiff` fuinction.

You can use `Date` instead of `Now` since you only need the date, and not the time.

If you use `DateDiff` you can keep the 2 values as `Date` variable, and instead of using `DateValue` with some `&` and `"/"`, you can have a shorter and cleaner version `DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(cell.Value), Day(cell.Value))`.

**Code**:

```
MsgBox DateDiff("d", DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(cell.Value), Day(cell.Value)), Date) > 1
```

If you want to get also the number of days between these 2 dates:

```
MsgBox DateDiff("d", DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(cell.Value), Day(cell.Value)), Date)
```

Comment: Well thought. And regarding February 29th, as @Slai adviced? 29/02/2017 for example, doesn't exists. Doesn't it give error?

Comment: I just had some tests (I changed my PC date also) and vba properly handles February 29th. It "converts" it to March 1st and the code goes well. I'm accepting your answer as the right one for this case. Thanks